# QODBC connects to SQL server but can not execute queries

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt, odbc

Title says most of what's going on. I can confirm that I'm connecting to the database and I'm definitely opening the connection before I try to make a query. The problem is, every time I send the query through exec(query), I'm getting an error stating that my QODBC driver isn't loaded. If that's really the case then how am I even getting a connection to start with? And more importantly how do I re-write my code or configure something so that my drivers are being loaded?

Some things to fill in the gaps:

- popupwindows.h is what is controlling AlertWindow, ErrorWindow, and Success Window and doesn't affect anything here at all.
- I'm getting all the constants and data just fine, so it's nothing in how I'm putting together my SQL query, example:

> INSERT INTO RegTable(Project_ID, Project_Name, Cycle, Number, B1, B2, B3, Horiz, Vert, Skew) VALUES (117.001, ZT400-300DPI, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

- I am getting true values for db.isOpen() and db.isValid() when I start the sendData() function, though I took them out once I ruled out errors with what they were checking.
- I have qsqlodbc.dll and qsqlodbcd.dll in several folders throughout my application directory, but most importantly in

  ```
  C:\path\to\built\project\debug\sqldrivers
  ```

Sorry for the wall-o-code but I wanted to make sure you all had everything you needed.

databaseconnection.cpp:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include "databaseconnection.h"
#include "popupwindows.h"

DatabaseConnection::DatabaseConnection(QWidget *parent, QString type) {
    this->setParent(parent);
    log = new EventLog("DatabaseConnection");
    connected = false;
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");        //note that this is a QString, not a QSqlDriver
    loadParams();
    connectDB(type);
}

DatabaseConnection::~DatabaseConnection() {
    db.close();
}

bool DatabaseConnection::connectDB( QString driverString) {
    if (!db.isOpen()) {
        if (db.isValid() && db.isDriverAvailable(driverString)) {
            QString connParams = QString("Driver={SQL SERVER};DSN=ODBCDriverForLocal;SERVER=" + server +";DATABASE="
                                     + database + ";Uid=" + username +";Pwd=" + password);
        db.setDatabaseName(connParams);
        log->print("Attempting to connect to database: " + connParams);
        if(!db.open()) {
            log->printerr("Could not connect to database: " + db.lastError().text());
            connected = false;
            ErrorWindow(0, "Database connection could not be established\n" + db.lastError().text());
               return false;
            } else {
                log->print("Database connection established.");
                connected = true;
                SuccessWindow(0, "Database connection established");
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            ErrorWindow(0, "Driver not available or valid.");
        }
    } return true;
}

void DatabaseConnection::disconnect() {
    if (db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
    }
}

void DatabaseConnection::loadParams() {
    QFile settings("dbSettings.txt");
    if (!settings.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        server = QString("Server String");
        database = QString("Database String");
        username = QString("Username");
        password = QString("Password");
    } else {
        QTextStream in(&settings);
        server = in.readLine();
        database = in.readLine();
        username = in.readLine();
        password = in.readLine();
    }
}

void DatabaseConnection::updateParams(QString params) {
    disconnect();
    QStringList parameters = params.split(";");
    server = parameters[0];
    database = parameters[1];
    username = parameters[2];
    password = parameters[3];
}

void DatabaseConnection::sendData(QString mode, QVector<QString> *data) {
    log->print("Prepping Data for Sending...");
    int cols;
    if(connectDB()) {
        db.exec(QString("USE " + database));
        QVector<QString> *dataQueue = new QVector<QString>;
        //collect all the data
        if (mode == QString("DK")) {
            extractData(mode, 15, 31, dataQueue, data);
            cols = 15;
        } else if (mode == QString("PQ")) {
            extractData(mode, 17, 200, dataQueue, data);
            cols = 17;
        } else {
            extractData(mode, 6, 200, dataQueue, data);
            cols = 6;
        }
        //create a query for each entry
        for (int i =0; i < (dataQueue->size() / cols); i++) {
            QString query("INSERT INTO ");
            emit requestConsts();
            if (mode == QString("Reg")) {
                 query += "RegTable(Project_ID, Project_Name, Cycle, Number, B1, B2, B3, Horiz, Vert, Skew) VALUES (";
            } else if (mode == QString("PQ")) {
                query += "PQTable(Project_ID, Project_Name, Cycle, Number, B1, B2, B3, [3DOTCD128_ScoreA], [3DOTCD128_GradeA],"
                     " [3DOTCD128_ScoreB], [3DOTCD128_GradeB], [10CR3DT128_Score], [10CR3DT128_Grade], [12CHAR3DOT39_Score],"
                     " [12CHAR3DOT39_Grade], [12CHAR4DOT39_Score], [12CHAR4DOT39_Grade], [2DOTDATAMATRIX_Score],"
                     " [2DOTDATAMATRIX_Grade], [3DOTDATAMATRIX_Score], [3DOTDATAMATRIX_Grade]) VALUES (";
            } else {
                 query += "DKTable(Project_ID, Project_Name, Cycle, Darkness, [3DOTCD128_ScoreA], [3DOTCD128_GradeA],"
                     " [3DOTCD128_ScoreB], [3DOTCD128_GradeB], [10CR3DT128_Score], [10CR3DT128_Grade], [12CHAR3DOT39_Score],"
                     " [12CHAR3DOT39_Grade], [12CHAR4DOT39_Score], [12CHAR4DOT39_Grade], [2DOTDATAMATRIX_Score],"
                     " [2DOTDATAMATRIX_Grade], [3DOTDATAMATRIX_Score], [3DOTDATAMATRIX_Grade]) VALUES (";
            }
            query += "" + constants;
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                int index = (i * cols) + j;
                query += ", " + dataQueue->at(index);
            }
            query += (")");
            log->print(query);
            QSqlQuery postedQuery = QSqlQuery(db);
            if (!postedQuery.exec(query)) {
                AlertWindow(0, this->lastError().text());
            }
        }
        //push the queries into action if not already being performed
        db.exec(QString("GO"));
        log->print("Data Sent.");
        SuccessWindow(0, "Data (theoretically) Sent!");
    }
}

void DatabaseConnection::getConsts(QString consts) {
    constants = consts;
}

void DatabaseConnection::extractData(QString mode, int cols, int rows, QVector<QString> *queue, QVector<QString> *data) {
    log->print("Extracting Data...");
    log->print(mode + " Mode");
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        QVector<QString> thisLine;
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            int index = (row * cols) + col;
            thisLine.append(data->at(index));
        }
        if (mode == QString("DK")) {
            if (!thisLine.at(0).isEmpty() && (!thisLine.at(1).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(3).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(5).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(7).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(9).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(11).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(13).isEmpty())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                    queue->append(thisLine.at(i));
                    //log->print(thisLine.at(i));
                }
            }
        } else if (mode == QString("PQ")) {
            if ((!thisLine.at(0).isEmpty() && !thisLine.at(1).isEmpty() && !thisLine.at(2).isEmpty()) || (!thisLine.at(5).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(7).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(9).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(11).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(13).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(15).isEmpty())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                    queue->append(thisLine.at(i));
                    //log->print(thisLine.at(i));
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ((!thisLine.at(0).isEmpty() && !thisLine.at(1).isEmpty() && !thisLine.at(2).isEmpty()) || (!thisLine.at(3).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(4).isEmpty() || !thisLine.at(5).isEmpty())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                    queue->append(thisLine.at(i));
                    //log->print(thisLine.at(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 6/21/16 - I've done some more research and found out I was using the DSN parameter incorrectly. My problem still stands even when I use it properly though, so no too much progress there, just some handy dandy learning.

Comment: Do you ever actually open the connection?

Comment: If you change `db.exec(QString("USE " + database));` to also use `QSqlQuery` will the error be already on that line? If I remember correctly you won't need the `USE $DB` at all, since this is already defined in the connection string. Would you try with a connection without using the DSN just to clarify there is no unrecognized problem during connect (see https://wiki.qt.io/ODBC)?

Comment: @SebastianLange, I did as you suggested and checking a QSqlQuery object's result for `"USE " + database` and there was no error raised, so I guess it's receiving some commands correctly. Unfortunately that kinda makes this even more confusing haha. I also removed the DSN (which is actually how I started this, without one), and the same "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded" error comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The things in VALUES needed to be contained in single quotes

`INSERT INTO RegTable(Project_ID, Project_Name, Cycle, Number, B1, B2, B3, Horiz, Vert, Skew) VALUES ('117.001', 'ZT400-300DPI', '0', '1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')`

Which seems kinda silly to me, but I'm sure there's a well thought out reason for this (if you know it, by all means enlighten me!). Thanks for the help those that did, it got me to here so as far as I'm concerned you answered the question :)

Side note: The error reporting is downright garbage for this. Both driver and database reporting "Drivers not loaded" isn't even kind of close to what was happening.